# How can I get a value from an array

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to solve this problem, I want to use these numbers one by one, but I cannot.

```java
String a = "101";
char[] array = a.toCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    // if i print array[i] it says 1 but in below,
    // it will give a reference. i want to get 1
    if (array[i] == 1) {
        System.out.print(1);
    } else {
        System.out.print(0);
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by `it will give a reference`?

Comment: according to String a while i=0 , it has to print 1 but it don't print 1 @xdhmoore

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what happens when you compare a char with an int like in your if statement but I suspect that may be the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Try this :***

```
    String a="101";
    char [] array=a.toCharArray();
    for(int i=0; i<array.length;i++) {
          if(array[i]== '1'){
            System.out.println(1);
        }else {
            System.out.println(0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you mate, what a bad mistake isn't it? :) i am sorry for this question. thank you again

Answer (score 1):

You can index the array by doing `array[...]` for example if we wanted to get the value of the first element in our array we would do `array[0]` as indexing starts from zero.

You could update your code to the following!

```
String a = "101";
char[] array = a.toCharArray();
for (int i = 0; I < array.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(array[i]);
}
```

If you wanted to print out both the element at index `i` and the index `i` you could replace the `println()` above with `System.out.println(i + " " + array[i])`.

Hope I properly understood your issue and this helped!

Comment: thank you actually my main issue is i want to write a code like bitwase calculator  it was the just a part of my code. For example for OR statement.. my main aim is compare two array and decide if there is a 1 for two array's first numbers then write 1...

Comment: Ah I see, I misunderstood the question, looks like you made a simple mistake within your code by checking if the value is a number rather than a char.